# LED on tactile button

Tags: arduino

I'm a beginner in Arduino. How do I wire the LED tactile button? Which of the pins of the LED tactile button is the anode and cathode of the LED and which are for the buttons?

[Tactile button with LED](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10442)

Comment: Normally I'd say, "Go read the [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/TSL12121.pdf)." But in this case I can see that you are hindered with un-rythmed palpable clag! And the so-called [drawing](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/TSD1265.png) is no better at explaining the pin-out A to F. From the breadboard photo, either pin E or pin F is common, but I can't tell whether that's common ground or common supply. Also, either pin A or pin D is common.

Comment: Also it is unknown if the part number is TSD1265 or TSL12121 or something else. The right address to ask about it is to complain to Sparkfun that their datasheets for that part are useless.

Comment: If the + and - markings on the [breadboard photo](https://cdn.sparkfun.com//assets/parts/4/9/3/0/Breadboard_shot.jpg) can be trusted (not connected backwards), then pin E or pin F is common ground, and pin A or pin D is common V+. I can't discern the orientation of the button to figure out which is E or F, nor which is A or D.

Comment: Use your multimeter set do "diode" mode, then measure the forward voltage between pins. When you have found a combination giving roughly some ~1V, then the + probe of the multimeter is on the anode and that's where you add the supply. Make sure to add a series resistor too, either before or after the LED, or otherwise it will go poof.

Comment: Can you see a "+" sign moulded into the white plastic? It shows up in [one of the photos](https://cdn.sparkfun.com//assets/parts/4/9/3/0/10442-03.jpg) on the page you linked to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good guess would be that it's a standard 12mm tact switch pinout with the two outrigger pins for the LED. Here is a similar product (diagram from [here](https://homyet.en.made-in-china.com/product/NyoEaubLCGcS/China-12-12mm-Through-Hole-Illuminated-Tactile-Swith-LED-Tact-Switch.html)). The similar product appears to have a red mark indicating the anode of the LED. There may be something molded into the plastic in the one you're looking at.

Note that there is no resistor in series with the LED. You probably know to add one, but I don't see any in that breadboard photo.

[image]

The layout is symmetrical so it can be rotated 180° to get the LED right without affecting the switch. Applying up to 5V in reverse to the LED won't hurt it (it just won't illuminate) so there is no danger in just trying it (assuming you have the resistor, otherwise your illuminated switch will likely quickly and permanently revert to being a non-illuminated type). They may be abusing an Arduino output in that photo, which is inadvisable.

Comment: Those LEDs look very bright in the breadboard photo!